# Java - How to avoid loss of precision during divide and cast to int?

Tags: java, casting, int, precision

I have a situation where I need to find out how many times an int goes into a decimal, but in certain cases, I'm losing precision.  Here is the method:

```
public int test(double decimalAmount, int divisor) {
  return (int) (decimalAmount/ (1d / divisor));
}
```

The problem with this is if I pass in 1.2 as the decimal amount and 5 as the divisor, I get 5 instead of 6.  How can I restrusture this so I know how many times 5 goes into the decimal amount as an int?

Comment: I think you need to give a more generalised version of the question - the terms you are using only make sense for integers ie 5 divides into 1.2 = 0/If you do improve the definition I suspect you will get the answer as I would suspect the issue is due to rounding

Comment: It's nothing to do with rounding and everything to do with the formula.A decimal divided by an int is simple (int)(decimalAmount/divisor). I think that's what David is looking for. As it stands that code is effectively doing a multiply of decimalAmount and divisor.

Answer (score 4):

The result of the computation is likely something like 5.999999999994, as the floating-point result is not necessarily exactly an integer. When you cast to an int, you truncate, and the result is 5. For another similar set of arguments, you might see a result of 6.0000000000002, and it would give you 6.

But the fact that this is so sensitive to floating-point representation calls into question why you think you want this -- maybe there's a better way to do what you wish to do. For example the answer above is correct, this simplifies, and then it's even less clear what the point is.

To really do what I think you imagine you want to do, you need to not use `double`s or `float`s. You need `java.util.BigDecimal` -- look up how it works. You can use it to "exactly" multiply 5 and 1.2 to get 6.

Comment: java.math.BicDecimal these days https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 3):

```
public int test(double decimalAmount, int divisor) {
  return (int) (divisor * decimalAmount);
}
```

Obviously, this is just multiplying then truncating.  Why you think you need this method?

Answer (score 3):

Floating point operations are not correct, they are approximations. By this operaton you could get for instance 5.9 as result. Casting it to int result into 5 (instead of 6). Try rounding instead of truncating:

```
public int test(double decimalAmount, int divisor) {
  return Math.round(divisor * decimalAmount);
}
```